# get all data from both tables

Tags: sql-server

I have the following tables

```
Tbl_T1
PRODUCT VALUE

A       10
C       30

Tb1_T2
PRODUCT VALUE

B       20
C       30
```

And I am looking for the output

```
PRODUCT VALUE1  VALUE2
A       10       0
B        0      20
C       30      30
```

Comment: Please, write your question correctly!

Comment: Add show text with question to explain what is problem and what is expected, instead of just posting table structure in question

Answer (score 0):

It is called a *full outer join*

```
select coalesce(t1.product, t2.product) as pr, 
       coalesce(t1.value, 0) as v1, 
       coalesce(t2.value, 0) as v2
from t1
full outer join t2 on t1.product = t2.product
```